# Vue.js : ID's are not displayed during the load of SVG file

Tags: vue.js, svg

I have a svg file that I am loading to my Component. Each path has an ID associated with a particular path. However, when I render my svg the IDs are not displayed. I attached some pictures to show first one is the svg code and the second one is the dom loaded in browser

Svg file

[image]

[image: Loaded DOM]

Comment: What build system are you using (cli, nuxt, etc)? What are you writing your templates in (html, pug, etc)?

Comment: Hi, I am using CLI and I am using html templates

Comment: If it makes difference I am using the inline style on paths

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So the problem was coming from vue-svg-loader and I was able to find a quick fix by adding the following to the vue.config. If anyone encounters the same issue. Basically add {cleanupIDs: false}, to the svgRule. Seems like by default vue-svg-loader removes the id's no idea why.

```
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: (config) => {
        const svgRule = config.module.rule('svg');

        svgRule.uses.clear();

        svgRule
            .use('vue-svg-loader')
            .loader('vue-svg-loader')
            .options({
                svgo: {
                    plugins: [
                        {removeDoctype: true},
                        {removeComments: true},
                        {cleanupIDs: false},
                        {collapseGroups: false},
                        {removeEmptyContainers: false}
                    ],
                },
            });
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the exactly the same problem. Assuming you're using `vue-svg-loader` to import the svg files, the issue is that the loader drops some attributes, including the IDs.

My solution was not to import the *svg* files, but rather paste the content directly into a *vue* component.

```
// myIcon.vue
<template>
   <svg version="1.1"...>
     <path id="81A" .../>
   </svg>
</template>
```

Now if you import *myIcon.vue*, all the attributes will be preserved.

Comment: Well that will not work for me, because there are many different svg files I have that I dynamically load